# Comment traduire « intellectualness » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, littérature

J'ai un passage de *On the Road* de Jack Kerouac à traduire en exercice et une phrase me pose particulièrement problème :

*Dean's intelligence was every bit as formal and shining and complete, without the tedious intellectualness.*

Qu'est-ce que Kerouac entend par "the tedious intellectualness" ? Est-ce qu'il fait référence à une tendance récurrente qu'ont les gens à vouloir tout problématiser, à étaler leurs facultés intellectuelles ?

Comment: C'est une question d'anglais plus qu'une question de français...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Je dirais tout simplement:

> intellectualité ennuyeuse

Oui je pense que les "intellectuels" peuvent par exemple avoir tendance a utiliser des mots, expressions, raisonnements compliqués (au moins du point de vue de Kerouac), et donc "tedious". Quoique Dean Moriarty utilise aussi des phrases a rallonges très compliquées, si je me souviens bien. Il y a peut-être aussi une dimension "pre counter-culture" dans l'évaluation de Kerouac.

Comment: Je ne peux pas ajouter de points car j'ai moins de 15 de réputation :( Merci beaucoup Frank !

Comment: Je vous ai upvoté (<- this is not correct French) pour augmenter vos points.

Answer (score 0):

[Intellectualité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/intellectualit%C3%A9) est neutre et traduit bien *[intellectualness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intellectualness)*.

Il est aussi possible de remplacer *tedious intellectualness* par un seul mot - [intellectualisme (B.)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/intellectualisme) - qui inclus déjà l'aspect péjoratif que Kerouac y associe.